# how to install and run a java app on android emulator

Tags: java, android, port

I have written a java program that takes screenshot of desktop... 
can i install this java app on android emulator and launch it by clicking on that..before installing on to emulator what all changes i should make to the java code and how to port it to the emulator later...

Thanks Manju

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you wrote your application in JavaSE (ordinary desktop Java), there will be complications on getting it to work on Android. The variant of Java that Android exposes has its own API for getting access to the Desktop. And worse, I'm pretty sure what you're positing is impossible on Android unless you have root access.

I suggest downloading ADT and running your application in an emulator to see what it does as soon as you can. As I said, the differences between Android and JavaSE are substantial and the sooner you try your code, the better.

Comment: Yes, while the ADB usb debugging channel can allow a PC to take a screenshot of an android device, ordinary applications running on the device itself are prevented from taking screenshots for security reasons.